# Json type objects and array mismatch

Tags: android, json

[

```
{
    "id":"20",
    "name":"sinha",
    "city":"new",
    "zone":"",
    "area":"delhi",
    "mobile":"9716515438",
    "address":"9716515438",
    "reg_date":"2015-02-28 20:29:10"
},
```

this is my json.

i am retrieving this in my app, but it shows json mismatch. i know i am doing object and array mismatch.

```
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
```

this is my log cat.

and this is my code. also please let me know if  i am taking the name of anything wrong.

```
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = " ";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
private static final String TAG_ZONE = "zone";
private static final String TAG_AREA = "area";
private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_REG_DATE = "reg_date";
JSONArray json_array = null;
ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                json_array = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);


                for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                    String zone = c.getString(TAG_ZONE);
                    String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                    String mobile = c.getString(TAG_MOBILE);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_REG_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error includes a line indicating where the error happened. You should indicate where the line is on your question.

Also, put the complete JSONArray that is failing, since you are using a JSONArray but your example contains only one JSONObject element, without the brackets opening/closing it.

Maybe that could be your error, since you are trying to put:

```
{
    "id":"20",
    "name":"sinha",
    "city":"new",
    "zone":"",
    "area":"delhi",
    "mobile":"9716515438",
    "address":"9716515438",
    "reg_date":"2015-02-28 20:29:10"
},
```

As a json array and it is a JSONObject